# How to go from one fragment to another fragment in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, fragment

I have a button in fragment A and when I click on fragment A, I want it to be redirected to fragment B. How to achieve this in kotlin? Right now I am using this code but app crash.

```
btntest.setOnClickListener {
            var intent = Intent(view.context, FragmentB::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

Comment: "How to achieve this in kotlin? Right now I am using this code but app crash." - and the crash is ... ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The way navigating of activity to activity is rather different with fragment to fragment, currently you're attempting to using intent to navigate to fragment, which probably causing the crash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you take a look on [the navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started). First, you create a Navigation resource file (usually referred to as Nav Graph), where you add the fragments you wish to connect.[image: navigation graph]
Make sure to give an ID to each fragment (that's what you'll use to navigate between them later). Additionally, you can use `app:startDestination` in order to set the first fragment to be shown.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    app:startDestination="@id/blankFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/blankFragment"
        android:name="com.example.cashdog.cashdog.BlankFragment"
        android:label="@string/label_blank"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_blank" />
</navigation>
```

Then, in the activity/fragment that will be hosting the fragments, add a `FragmentContainerView` and set the graph to the one you created.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Finally, in order to navigate between fragments, use this in the Activity that is hosting the navigation (use `getActivity()` if a Fragment is hosting the navigation).

```
// as per defined in your FragmentContainerView
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController

// Navigate using the IDs you defined in your Nav Graph
navController.navigate(R.id.blankFragment)
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Edit: if you want to access the controller within your `Fragment`, use `activity?.supportFragmentManager` to get the fragment manager.

Comment: But fragment instance is lost

Answer (score 1):

Try this in From Fragment, after you have set action in nav graph xml.

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_from_fragmentA_to_fragmentB)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `MainActivity` write this code:

```
    val transaction=supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction() 
    val firstFragment =FirstFragment() 
  transaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainerV,firstfragment).commit()
```

and fragmentContainerView should be implemented in `activity_main.xml` and in `FirstFragment` write the below code:

```
    loginBinding.btnLogin.setOnClickListener {
    
      val secondFragment =SecondFragment()
      val transaction=requireActivity().supportFragmentManager
.beginTransaction()
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainerV,secondFragment)
                transaction.commit()
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

set in adapter click listner

loadFragment(SettingFragment())

```
private fun loadFragment(homeFragment: SettingFragment) {
    val transaction = (context as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.container,homeFragment)
    transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    transaction.commit()
}
```

Comment: Question is about Fragment A to B there is no adapter involved. 
Now we have navigation component which provides much more flexibility and more maintainable code with safe args.